# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

forgive me for my language .
i installed cordova several times ago and it worked and created and released projects before .. i set up new windows this time i installed cordova using the same steps every time on the same windows version 10 i when i write the command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

it give me this error:

> Failed to install
>   'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5) Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
>   code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)

please any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an error due to having an old JDK.

1. Install the most recent JDK (Java SE Development Kit) for your system. If you are using 64-bit Windows I recommend getting the x64 JDK.
2. Open advanced system settings
3. Open the Environment Variables window
4. Update the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the new JDK. e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"
5. Open a new command window and try again.

Comment: I am now able to add the platform.. but i still can't install the plugin "Cordova-plugin-whitelist"  the most common reason is the update of Cordova.

Comment: Still the same error message? Does the command "cordova requirements android" give any useful information?